# Can't scrape tile; Python dictionary returns 'None'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a job title from Indeed.com.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class JobsNySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'jobs_ny'
    allowed_domains = ['www.indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=analyst&l=New%20York,%20NY&vjk=b588911bd50d7ab1']

    def parse(self, response):
       jobs = response.xpath("//td[@class='resultContent']")
       for job in jobs:
           yield {
            'title': job.xpath(".//h2[@class='jobTitle']/span/text()").get()
           }
    
       next_page=response.urljoin(response.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination-list']/li[position() = last()]/a/@href").get())

       if next_page:
           yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

For some reason, Python dictionary returns {'title': None}.
I disabled JavaScript to make sure I am scraping HTML markup.

Comment: Looks like `job.xpath(...).get()` returned `None`. What is your question about it?

Comment: I was wondering why it returned None instead of text string

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the `get()` method? What does it say about when it returns `None` or something else?

Comment: get() returns None if the value is not present in the dictionary. But why is the value not present?

Comment: Because no elements in the page match the xpath selectors you used.

Comment: That is what I thought but I had checked the xpath selectors multiple times and couldn't identify what selector was wrong. Thank you, I guess I will keep looking into the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath selector for the `title` is incorrect because you are using the selector `@class='jobTitle'` yet the `h2` element has multiple classes on it so your selector will not find a matching element. Try using the contains function as shown below.

```py
yield {
   'title': job.xpath(".//h2[contains(@class,'jobTitle')]/span/text()").get()
}
```

Alternatively, ensure you capture all the classes on the element if you want to select using `@class=...`. This might be unstable since some classes might change from time to time. See below sample

```py
yield {
   'title': job.xpath(".//h2[@class='jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple']/span/text()").get()
}
```

I recommend using the `contains` function with the class name that is common on all the elements you want to select.